# How to add checkboxes to UITableViewCell??

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, sdk

some time ago someone already asked this question and a few answers were given but i didn't really understand any of them. So i was wondering if anyone could please write an easy to understand tutorial on how to do the things shown on the image below:

http://img208.yfrog.com/img208/6119/screenshotkmr.png

I would be so greatful if anyone can share exactly how to this because it looks really cool and i would love to use something similar in my application :-)!

Comment: read this link http://walkingsmarts.com/creating-radio-button-and-checkbox-lists-using-uitableview/ it may help you

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Make a unchecked and checked image..

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    if ([selectedRowsArray containsObject:[contentArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]) {
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"];
    }
    else {
       cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"];
    }
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleChecking:)];
    [cell.imageView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
    cell.imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES; //added based on @John 's comment
    //[tap release];

    cell.textLabel.text = [contentArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

- (void) handleChecking:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapRecognizer {
    CGPoint tapLocation = [tapRecognizer locationInView:self.tableView];
    NSIndexPath *tappedIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:tapLocation];

    if ([selectedRowsArray containsObject:[contentArray objectAtIndex:tappedIndexPath.row]]) {
        [selectedRowsArray removeObject:[contentArray objectAtIndex:tappedIndexPath.row]];
    }
    else {
        [selectedRowsArray addObject:[contentArray objectAtIndex:tappedIndexPath.row]];
    }
    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:tappedIndexPath] withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
```

Comment: indexForRowAtPoint is not a recognized accessor on UITableView... how do I get it to work?

Comment: Sorry that should be indexPathForRowAtPoint:.. Code is now Corrected

Comment: hm it still doesn't seem to recognize any specific taps on the cell.imageView. any ideas?

Comment: I tried the code but nothing worked, i got an Error in the first UITapGestureRecogniser line saying it is not used.. Do i need to add it in .h? if yes, then how? and are there any frameworks I need to Add? 

Thanks

Comment: UIGestureRecognizers are apart of the UIKIT framework so it should not need to be added..
What iOS do you code for? UIGestureRecognizers are available from 3.2 and later..

Comment: the cell.imageView must be enabled for userInteraction, so just add cell.imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES; then the above code will work fine.

Comment: How did you declare selectedRowsArray?

Comment: And whats the difference between contentArray and selectedRowsArray?

Comment: cellForRowAtIndexPath: doesn't remove old gestureRecognizers.

Comment: Perhaps instead init the gesture recognizer within the "if(cell == nil)"

Answer (score 1):

One of the way I can think of is you do custom UITableViewCell ([this tutorial](http://adeem.me/blog/2009/05/30/iphone-sdk-tutorial-part-6-creating-custom-uitableviewcell-using-interface-builder-uitableview/) is good for starting. This is [another, similar one](http://www.e-string.com/content/custom-uitableviewcells-interface-builder)). Inside the custom UITableViewCell you need to put a UIButton there with a circle image. When user select the button, you change the image to the green circle