# Multiple Check Box in UITableview iPhone

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I am new in iOS
I am creating dynamically buttons in my tableview
i had set a image on button for check and uncheck
What i have to do is when i tap(or check) on button the data on indexpath row will add in my array.
And if i deselect it , data removes from my array. Please Help me

```
-(void)btnForCheckBoxClicked:(id)sender
{

UIButton *tappedButton = (UIButton*)sender;

indexForCheckBox= [sender tag];


if([tappedButton.currentImage isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox_unchecked.png"]]) 
{

    [sender  setImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"checkbox_checked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    strinForCheckBox= [ApplicationDelegate.ArrayForSearchResults objectAtIndex:indexForCheckBox];
    [arrForCheckBox addObject:strinForCheckBox];
    NSLog(@"Sender Tag When Add %d", indexForCheckBox);
    NSLog(@"Array Count Check Box %d",[arrForCheckBox count]);

}

else
{

        [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox_unchecked.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [arrForCheckBox removeObjectAtIndex:indexForCheckBox];
        NSLog(@"Sender Tag After Remove %d", indexForCheckBox);
        NSLog(@"Array Count Uncheck Box %d",[arrForCheckBox count]);


   }


}
```

Comment: I can't understand really what you need help with! Provide some code if possible in your question!

Comment: @Haris I have understand his Question.

Comment: Thanks to @Haris i have posted code of button click event and in tablev cell for row at indexpath method i am creating buttons dynamically

Answer (score 2):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    if ([selectedRowsArray containsObject:[contentArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]) {
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"];
    }
    else {
       cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"];
    }
    UITapGestureRecogniser *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleChecking:)
    [cell.imageView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
    [tap release];

    cell.textLabel.text = [contentArray objectAtIndex];
    return cell;
}

- (void) handleChecking:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapRecognizer {
    CGPoint tapLocation = [tapRecognizer locationInView:self.tableView];
    NSIndexPath *tappedIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:tapLocation];

    if (selectedRowsArray containsObject:[contentArray objectAtIndex:tappedIndexPath.row]) {
        [selectedRowsArray removeObject:[contentArray objectAtIndex:tappedIndexPath.row]];
    }
    else {
        [selectedRowsArray addObject:[contentArray objectAtIndex:tappedIndexPath.row]];
    }
    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:tappedIndexPath] withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this question has been answered some time ago! Check it out first and tell us if this is what you are looking for ?

[How to add checkboxes to UITableViewCell??](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3666629/iphone-sdk-how-to-add-checkboxes-to-uitableviewcell)

[image http://img208.yfrog.com/img208/6119/screenshotkmr.png](http://img208.yfrog.com/img208/6119/screenshotkmr.png)

Comment: I like this type but my problem is about store values in array after selecting and on deselecting remove it from array hope you understand

Answer (score 0):

You can add this on your button click method.

First set Bool value which set yes on one click and No In second click and when you first click add that index value in array using array addobject property and other click removeobject property.

```
-(void)list
{

if(isCheck==YES)
{
    //add array object  here
    isCheck=NO;
}
else if(isCheck==NO)
{
  //remove array object here
   isCheck=YES;
}

}
```

Comment: you pass that object only which you create in didselectrow tableview method and pass that object in here.

Answer (score 0):

I have found another way. Code extracted from [@The Saad](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10461589/940096) And, i had just modified with key/value pairs as useful one like below code -

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    if ([[selectedRowsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] containsObject:@"YES"])
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"];
    else
       cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"];

    UITapGestureRecogniser *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleChecking:)
    [cell.imageView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
    [tap release];

    cell.textLabel.text = [contentArray objectAtIndex];
    return cell;
}

- (void) handleChecking:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapRecognizer {
    CGPoint tapLocation = [tapRecognizer locationInView:self.tableView];
    NSIndexPath *tappedIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:tapLocation];

    if ([[selectedRowsArray objectAtIndex:tappedIndexPath.row] containsObject:@"YES"])
        [selectedRowsArray replaceObjectAtIndex:tappedIndexPath.row withObject:[NSSet setWithObject:@"NO"]];
    else
        [selectedRowsArray replaceObjectAtIndex:tappedIndexPath.row withObject:[NSSet setWithObject:@"YES"]];

    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:tappedIndexPath] withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
```

Add, the objects for `selectedRowsArray` as below with the count of your `self.tableView`'s row count. So, you need to add the bool values as below

```
for ( int i = 0; i < tableViewRowCount; i++ ) { // tableViewRowCount would be your tableView's row count
    ....
    ....
    ....
    [selectedRowsArray addObject:[NSSet setWithObject:@"NO"]];
    ....
    ....
}
```

Hope this helps! Cheers!

**Update**

With the use of updated code you don't need to keep key/value pair of `NSMutableDictionary` for overkilling that. `NSSet` provides you better way with this.