# How to get text and image from server in IOS

Tags: ios, json, checkbox

I am new to **IOS**. My company owner has told me to create an  **IOS**  application in which I have to take text and image url in json format from server. I have gone through many examples but did n't got the proper solution. Moreover I have to create **dynamic checkboxes** and **buttons** after loading data from **json**. The id and text will be assigned to those created checkboxes. I have already designed an **Android** app for this so for your convenience I am showing you the snapshot of that app.For checkboxes I refer this link : [getcategories](http://test2.sonasys.net/Android/UserCategoryList?UserID=1).

[image].

Note that the checkboxes that are shown in image is dynamically created.

In my **Android** App I used **ListView** to assign all downloaded text at their own place in the list.But i don't know how to do it in **IOS**.For user post i refer this link: [getuserpost](http://test2.sonasys.net/Android/GetPosts?UserID=1).

[image]

I have already visited these links:
[1.Appcoda](http://www.appcoda.com/parse-xml-and-json-web-service/).
[2.Touch-Code](http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/how-to-fetch-and-parse-json-by-using-data-models/).

So finally I want following things:

1.*how to create dynamic **checkboxes** and assign id and text from Json string*.

2.*How to get several text from **json** and assign to **IOS UITableView***

I would appreciate all answers

Comment: What exactly do you want to know? How to make server requests in ios or how to display images from url?

Comment: Your question us too generic. Try to make it concise for what you are not able to achieve. Currently it looks like you are asking about whole screen UI for both screens.

Comment: You did not understand my question .I have shown images also

Comment: In that case I would suggest you to read about the UI components of iOS and check what fits where. If you have any question about any part in particular I will be able to suggest a way.

Comment: @amit do you have any suggested link which can solve my both problem as mentioned at the end of question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many links/tutorials to help you for your problems as these are pretty basics. I will try to put some useful links here:

1. For creating dynamic checkboxes: In iOS there is no native component as checkbox. We need to implement it with the help of :

   -`UIButton` : By having a button with check/uncheck image and a text on it.

   -With help of a `UITableView` in which each cell has a button to chow check uncheck mark with some text.

   links: [Sample Code](https://github.com/ardalahmet/SSCheckBoxView), [relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10461504/multiple-check-box-in-uitableview-iphone)
2. get several text from json and assign to IOS UITableView :

   [Table View tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/uitableview-tutorial-storyboard-xcode5/), [another tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-tutorial-create-a-simple-table-view-app/)