# reloading data of a table view is not working

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

im making a tableview with checkboxes. I did implement the checkboxes with UIButtons and i can check and uncheck them without problems. The problem came up when i tried to make a "select/unselect all" button and this is the resultant code:

```
-(IBAction)select:(id)sender{
    if (all==YES) {
        all=NO;
    }
    else {
        all=YES;
    }
    [tblPeticiones reloadData];
}
```

The problem is that the table doesn't reload the data.
Any idea?
Thanks and regards.

EDIT:
I load de data like this

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  //Datos
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];

    NSString *fInicio = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[(MAP_Gastos_CiberTRIPS *)[m objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] DEP_DATE]];
    NSString *loc = [(MAP_Gastos_CiberTRIPS *)[m objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] LOCATION];
    NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
    [formatter setCurrencyCode:@"EUR"];
    [formatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
    NSString *precio = [formatter stringFromNumber:aux];
//Vista
    NSString *MyIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"MyIdentifier %i", indexPath.row];

    CustomTVC *cell = (CustomTVC *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[CustomTVC alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
        //CheckBox
        UIButton *checkButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

        [checkButton setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 23, 23)];
        if (todos==NO) {
            [checkButton setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkNO.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:10.0 topCapHeight:0.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
             checkButton.tag = 0;
        }
        else {
            [checkButton setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkSI.png"] str    etchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:10.0 topCapHeight:0.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 
            checkButton.tag = 1;
        } 

        [checkButton addTarget:self action:@selector(checkAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        [cell addSubview:checkButton];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:checkButton]; 
  //fecha
        UILabel *label = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 0, 70.0,tableView.rowHeight)] autorelease];
        [cell addColumn:0];
        label.tag = 1;
        label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12.0];
        label.text = fInicio;
        label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
        label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        //label.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        label.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:label]; 


        if (indexPath.row % 2 == 0){ 
            label.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:233.0/255.0 
                                               green:233.0/255.0 
                                                blue:233.0/255.0 
                                               alpha:1.0]; 
        } else { 
            label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; 

        }


        //localización
        label =  [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(115, 0, 75.0,tableView.rowHeight)] autorelease];
        [cell addColumn:180];
        label.tag = 2;
        label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12.0];
        label.text = loc;
        label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
        label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        //label.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        label.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:label];

        if (indexPath.row % 2 == 0){ 
            label.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:233.0/255.0 
                                                green:233.0/255.0 
                                                 blue:233.0/255.0 
                                                alpha:1.0]; 
        } else { 
            label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];     
        }
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: my be u have not properly connected datasource and delegate to tableview

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3666629/iphone-sdk-how-to-add-checkboxes-to-uitableviewcell

Comment: @SmartWork the datasource and delegate are connected to the tableview and the tableview is connected on the XIB

Comment: @laxonline i had no problems inserting a checkbox in the rows. The problem occurs when i try to select all of them by reloading the tableview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the problem. This is the working code:

```
-(IBAction)select:(id)sender{

    if (all==YES) {
        all=NO;
        [btnSelAll setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkSI.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:10.0 topCapHeight:0.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 

    }else {

        all=YES;
        [btnSelAll setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkNO.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:10.0 topCapHeight:0.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 
    }
    NSMutableArray *arrIndex = [NSMutableArray new];
    for(int i=0;i<[m count];i++) {
        [arrIndex addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];
    }
    [self.tblPeticiones beginUpdates];
    [tblPeticiones reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:arrIndex withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    [self.tblPeticiones endUpdates]; 
    [tblPeticiones reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Debug the problem
Check datasource methods of tableView  whether they are being called or not after reload?

Comment: datasource methods are not being called (well, they are called when i scroll down, but they are not responding to reloadData instruction)

Answer (score 0):

You should store which rows are checked in an array. Then check this array when you load / reload the tableview (in cellForRowAtIndex) to see if the row should be checked.

Then if you want to select all or none, just delete or add them to the array and reload the tableview.

If you need help implementing this, let me know.

Comment: thats not a problem: i want to set all the cells as checked, and i do it. The problem is that i cant reload data (well, i do reload data, but only data thats isnt showing at the moment)

Comment: Could you then post more of your TableView methods / creation, so we can see what might go wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Some comments about your code:

- There seems to be global variable called `all`, whose value you toggle, when button is pressed. However inside cellForRowAtIndexPath you check value of another global variable called `todos`. Is there some connection between these variables?
- You change checkbox background image only, when you create a new cell. Since cells are recycled, you need to move this code outside `if (cell == nil)` i.e. afterwards, where you are customizing a recycled cell
- You should only check whether `if (todos)` and `if (!todos)`, don't compare to values like YES or NO. Also easiest way to toggle a boolean is `todos = !todos` :)

Comment: Thanks but i put the solution there up. The first point was just a mistake translating (or forgot to translate xD). Youre right in the second point, i didnt realize about it but i found another way to do it. In the third point, i prefer to do it like this because i dont know who will read my code and also dont know his level.
Thanks for your help, i really didnt realize about the second point, i will keep it in mind for the next time :)