# how to add checkboxes button in UITableViewCell objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I know here so many answers of this question but i unable to get proper meaning to all.

I want to button selection not cell. by default button is unchecked  and if some one click or press button than button is changed to checked(only presses button) not a all.

I mentioned my screenshot and code there is button , array's values (appliances's name) and something with switch button

**code**

```
-(IBAction)SelectAppliance:(id)sender {
    UIButton *btn=(UIButton*)sender;
    NSLog(@"button tag is :%ld",(long)btn.tag);
    NSLog(@"click button"); 
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [_arrApplnc count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"SceneTableViewCell";

    SceneTableViewCell *cell = (SceneTableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    if(checked) { 
         [cell.btnRadio setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    } else {
         [cell.btnRadio setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

    cell.btnRadio.tag = indexPath.row;
    cell.lblName.text =[[_arrApplnc valueForKey:@"applianceName"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell.btnRadio addTarget:self action:@selector(SelectAppliance:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    return cell;
}
```

[image: UI Screenshort]

Comment: You have explained what you want, but not what your question is; What isn't working? It would also help if you indented your code and added newlines where appropriate.  You certainly don't want to add an action handler in `cellForRowAt` as you will end up with multiple handlers when the cell is re-used.

Comment: @Paulw11 than what have to do?

Comment: Normally you would have the cell act as the button tap handler and advise the view controller about the button tap via a delegation pattern. It is probably even nicer to just use the `didSelect` table delegate method; that way the user can tap anywhere on the cell to select/deselect

Comment: but select/deselect only working on cell not button

Comment: Correct. I would use a `UIImageView` to show the checkbox and just use the `didSelect` function (call `deselect` in your `didSelect` handler so that the cell is immediately deselected), otherwise put the button tap handler in the subclass and use a delegation pattern as I suggested

Comment: yaa i also put in tap but its not working here link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3666629/how-to-add-checkboxes-to-uitableviewcell

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182318/discussion-between-paulw11-and-krishna-kushwaha).

Comment: You may also disable user's interaction with the button. That way the touches will go to the cell and not the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to use a button in the cell, I would suggest using a delegation pattern so that the cell itself handles the button tap and sends a message to the view controller.

In **SceneTableViewCell.h**

```
@protocol SceneTableViewCellDelegate <NSObject>
@optional
    - (void)checkBoxTapped:(SceneTableViewCell *)cell;
@end

@interface SceneTableViewCell : NSObject
    @property (nonatomic, weak) id <SceneTableViewCellDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

In **SceneTableViewCell.m**

```
-(IBAction)checkboxTapped:(UIButton *)sender {
    [self.delegate checkBoxTapped:self];
}
```

In your **ViewController.m**

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSMutableIndexSet *checkedRows;

- (void) viewDidLoad {
    self.checkedRows = [[NSMutableIndexSet alloc]init];

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"SceneTableViewCell";

    SceneTableViewCell *cell = (SceneTableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.delegate = self
    }


    if([self.checkedRows contains:indexPath.row]) { 
         [cell.btnRadio setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    } else {
         [cell.btnRadio setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

    cell.lblName.text =[[_arrApplnc valueForKey:@"applianceName"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

- (void) checkBoxTapped:(SceneTableView Cell *)cell {

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    if ([self.checkedRows contains: indexPath.row]) {
        [self.checkedRows removeIndex: indexPath.row];
    } else {
        [self.checkedRows addIndex: indexPath.row];
    }

    [tableView reloadRowsAt:@[indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}
```

Another approach would be to simply to use a `UIImageView` in the cell rather than a `UIButton` and use the `didSelect` handler to toggle the checked state.  That way the user can tap anywhere in the cell.

Comment: thanks for quickly response but previously i told i unable to delegate bcz i get error is i write same this code

Comment: What is the error?  This is a perfectly standard delegation pattern implementation

Comment: if i write [self.delegate checkBoxTapped:self]; in button than method is not found

Comment: Not in the button, in the cell

Comment: @Pauw11 sorry i missed something but i unable to find out

Comment: hey bro i made two section prob is that if i click first section 1 row than why are select second section first row ?

Comment: If you have more than one section then you will need an array of `NSMutableIndexSet` - one for each section

Comment: yaa i taken another indexset array but im little confused that how to determine this line - NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tableView indexPathForCell:cell]; . its auto get in two different indexset or not  (yaa maybe we need to any condition )

Comment: i tried bro but it is unable to determine section so its not working. i take another index set array but none of get.

Comment: The section is just `indexPath.section`.  You should ask another question, showing the relevant code