# In tableview, if select section 1 row 1 then why is second section row 1 selected also?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I used a cell tapped method with check button.
If I select the first section and first row then it automatically selects the second section first row. Meaning if you select any row then it is selecting the same row in another section. I don't understand why.

I also tried section condition (`indexpath.section ==0`) or something another section condition. I have two arrays so I take manually 2 section and row will depend on the condition.

```
if(section ==0) { return arra1.count } else { return arr2.count }
```

Previously I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52941938/how-to-add-checkboxes-button-in-uitableviewcell-objective-c/52942956?noredirect=1#comment92795992_52942956) implementation.

[image: select first section 1 row]

[image: see also select second section same row ?]

Comment: share your `cellForRow` & `didSelectRow` methods

Comment: code is already mention code link in my question  and i didnt use didselect method i take empty.

Comment: @Krishnakushwaha you should post your code here. I hope you know how to get help from others for free.

Answer (score 0):

Finally resolve my problem. i just take two indexset array. if checkbutton tap by first section than i store addindex in nsmutable indexset arr1 and same thing for second section  after that i check condition

```
if ([self.arr1 containsIndex: indexPath.row]) {
         [self.arr1 removeIndex: indexPath.row];
     } else {
         [self.arr1 addIndex:indexPath.row];
     }
       [_tblVScene reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

if ([self.arr2 containsIndex: indexPath.row]) {
         [self.arr2 removeIndex: indexPath.row];
     } else {
         [self.arr2 addIndex:indexPath.row];
     }
       [_tblVScene reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
```

Comment: You don't need to do this. Table view gives this information for free. Read more about table views and how it reuse cells.